# Adding ngInit to all the elements with specified css class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a single page application (angularjs + angular-ui-router) and there are many elements with 'someCssClass'.

I need to add a global handler (at window object), that handles all these elements init event. Is there a way to do this, except manually adding ngInit (or some like this) for each element in each view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with directive and `link`option.

```
app.directive('someCssClass', function () {
 return {
  restrict: 'C',
  link: function initHandler(scope, element, attrs){}
 };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woefn3f1/).

Angular directive has `restrict` parameter, which could be class. As you already have classes on elements — you could use them.

And `$emit`/`$on` for events, with what data you need.